# XCode or Eclipse for Cocos2d-x targeted for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, linux, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have been using Eclipse on Arch Linux for a long time developing android apps and games. Now I want to try Cocos2d-x and wonder if I should develop a new project in XCode on MacOS or in Eclipse on Linux.

I did a lot of research and found many tips on how to create android project ready to use in Eclipse from XCode project, but I didn't find any tips about which IDE is better.

I am not familiar with MacOS and XCode, but I think that this is not a problem at all.

I suppose that setting up the environment on Linux can take much more time and this is a resource which is very important to me.

I also find out that there are many tutorials on Cocos2d-x targeted to XCode than developing on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried installing cocoa-2dx for gaming solution for both iOS and Android. In iOS it was very simple, by following the below steps,

Running the code in iOS:
1. extract cocoa 2d-x and then run the following command the root folder 
sudo ./install-template-xcode.sh ~u ~f
2. Cocoa2d-x templates will be installed, when Xcode is opened we can see the cocoa2d-x templates listed in iOS. 
3. Choose the template from the cocoa2d-x and build a sample program say hello world and run, you will see the helloworld program on the screen.

For android, setting up the environment takes lot of time, followed the steps provided in the below link, and could set up the environment with some difficultly because i come from iOS background. 
http://lancedev.blogspot.in/2012/08/setting-up-cocos2d-x-for-android-and.html

The above link is can be used if you want to support cross platform. Otherwise you can use the java project in cocoa2d itself directly in Android and it works

Comment: Did you make it work on android finally? Did you setup your android environment on MacOS?

Comment: I was trying to install it in macOS and could run the android project.

Comment: If you are not trying to support any cross platform then you can use the java project in cocoa2d, It works in Andoird environment.

Comment: Yes, I target iOS and Android only, but prefer c++ rather than java